# how to dereference these function pointers

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I am confused by function pointers . I know there must exist some `rules` which can help me to dereference such pointers.

For examples:

```
1) void *(*(*fp1)(int))[10];
2) float (*(*fp2)(int, int, int))(int);
3) int (*(*fp3)())[10]();
```

Can anyone help me to overwhelm such obstacles.

Comment: See [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: Calling the functions is easy enough: `(*fp1)(0)`; `(*fp2)(1, 2, 3)` and `(*fp3)()`.  The tricky bit is the type of the return values.  Those are absurd; you're extremely unlikely to see anything as contorted as any of those in real life.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "you're extremely unlikely to see anything as contorted as any of those in real life" - try writing a prototype for `signal` without using typedefs.

Comment: To confirm your interpretation of those, you might use cdecl.  Here is an example: (sorry for the formating):                                                     $ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain void *(*(*fp1)(int))[10]
declare fp1 as pointer to function (int) returning pointer to array 10 of pointer to void
cdecl>

Comment: @immibis: OK; I concede that `fp2` in the question is comparable to a function pointer for `signal()`.  Looking at it again, I think it has a superfluous set of parentheses, too.  But the ones involving the pointers to arrays are much less likely to be encountered in 'real life'.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to rewrite the pointer declaration with words:

1 )

`void *(*(*fp1)(int))[10];` is an array of `void *(*(*fp1)(int))`

And a `void *(*(*fp1)(int))` is a pointer to a `void *(*fp1)(int)`

And a `void *(*fp1)(int)` is a pointer to a function that takes a single `int` and returns `void*`.

So, fp1 is an array of pointers to pointers to `void*(int)` functions.

So, if you want to call the first function, you should first get the 1st element (`[0]`), then dereference the double pointer to single pointer and then call: `void* returnvalue = (*(fp1[0]))(42);`

2 )

The second one is pretty simple: it's just a pointer to a function pointer that takes 3 ints and returns a float.

Remember: when you want to call a function by pointer you need to use a single level pointer (`*` not `**`) and you can't dereference it any further.

3 )

The third one is a little harder:

`int (*(*fp3)())[10]();`

This is actually a function definition.

There is a function fp3, that takes no parameters, and returns:

`int (*(*fp3)())[10]`

which is almost like the first example except the return value is different.

So, fp3 is a function, that returns an array of `int (*(*fp3)())`, which are pointers to pointers to `int()` functions.

So fp3 is a function, that returns an array of pointers to pointers to functions that take no parameters and return an `int`

If you spot any mistakes, or if I didn't explain something, write a comment